# How can I get the number of entities by type?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have tried to get it using:

```
http://ip:1026/v2/entities?type=Audi&details=on
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
GET /v2/entities?type=Audi&options=count
```

You should get the count in the `fiware-total-count` header in the response.

Maybe you find useful the [pagination documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/pagination/index.html) in the Orion manual.

Comment: I've tried to use it but it doesn't work. http://cad-pilot.secureiot.eu:1026/v2/entities?type=Audi&options=count

Comment: I have done the same query and I get `Fiware-Total-Count: 113`. Are you looking to the *headers* in the response?